# How to import icons from FontAwesome and shake all the unused ones?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, rollup

Our current implementation loads all of the icons into the font awesome `library`:

```js
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons';
import { far } from '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons';
import { fat } from '@fortawesome/pro-thin-svg-icons';
import { fad } from '@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons';

library.add(fas, far, fat, fad);
```

So now we can use string literals for our icons

```js
<FontAwesomeIcon
      {...props}
      icon={[
        icon.type,
        icon.name,
      ]}
    />
```

The problem is, font awesome size is huge (around 10mb) in our bundle.

I have tried using dynamic import https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons#dynamic-icon-importing by passing the name of the icon to a component, but it failed as Babel doesn't support such macro.

My question is, following font awesome docs, what are the best practices to import icons and shake the unused ones?